# Why is calling free() changing the memory addresses of a different pointer?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm implementing a circularly linked list and am attempting to make the functions that will free the linked list and the nodes in the linked list.  I have a `LL_t` type that points to the head and tail of the linked list.  And then a linked list of `LL_node_t` nodes.

I have done my best to get the important parts of the code and the output that I am working with to better show my question.

My question is, why in my `temp_llnode_ptr` start with this value `temp_llnode_ptr: 0x7fffcf9c7310`, but after calling my free function end up with `NEW temp_llnode_ptr: 0x7fffcf9c6010`.  It starts with the address of my second node.  I attempt to free my first node.  Then after the function my `temp_llnode_ptr` has a different value.

```
void 
free_LL (LL_t** list)
{
    LL_node_t** temp_llnode_ptr = NULL;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (*list)->LL_length; i++)
    {
        printf("Inside FOR loop\n");

        printf("list->head: %p\n", (void*)(*list)->head);
        printf("list->tail: %p\n", (void*)(*list)->tail);

        temp_llnode_ptr = &(*list)->head->next;
        printf("temp_llnode_ptr: %p\n", (void*)(*temp_llnode_ptr));
        printf("(*temp_llnode_ptr)->next: %p\n", (void*)(*temp_llnode_ptr)->next);


        free_LL_node(&(*list)->head);
        printf("NEW temp_llnode_ptr: %p\n", (void*)(*temp_llnode_ptr));
        printf("NEW list->head: %p\n", (void*)(*list)->head);

    }
}

void 
free_LL_node (LL_node_t** node)
{
    (*node)->next = NULL;
    (*node)->data = NULL;
    printf("node about to be FREED is: %p\n", (void*)(*node));
    free(*node);
    *node = NULL;
}

OUTPUT FROM PRINT FUNC (The nodes in my linked list)
Node#: 0 | Current node: 0x7fffcf9c72f0 | Node data: 10 | Next node 0x7fffcf9c7310
Node#: 1 | Current node: 0x7fffcf9c7310 | Node data: 20 | Next node 0x7fffcf9c7330
Node#: 2 | Current node: 0x7fffcf9c7330 | Node data: 30 | Next node 0x7fffcf9c72f0

Inside FOR loop
list->head: 0x7fffcf9c72f0
list->tail: 0x7fffcf9c7330
temp_llnode_ptr: 0x7fffcf9c7310   <--- Why do these change?
(*temp_llnode_ptr)->next: 0x7fffcf9c7330
node about to be FREED is: 0x7fffcf9c72f0
NEW temp_llnode_ptr: 0x7fffcf9c6010   <--- Why do these change?
NEW list->head: (nil)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1) Why not? 2) How would you know? You are not allowed to read that address after calling `free`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  As you can see ```list->head``` gets freed and set to null in the output.  My ```temp_llnode_ptr``` is pointing at the second node.  But after calling free() it gets changed.

Comment: Once you call `free()` the pointer value is considered indeterminate, and trying to use it (even just printing it) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @sj95126 I'm not using the the value after freeing it.  That's not even what the question is about.  I'm wondering why the pointer value of the next node in the list is changing.

Comment: That is what your title is saying. But actually you seem to mean memory where the free'd memory was pointing to.

Comment: @Gerhardh I changed the title as I see how it was misleading.  I am calling free() on the head node.  My ```temp_llnode_ptr``` points to the second node in the list.  Why does this get changed after calling free is what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: I am not sure you are printing or freeing what you think you are. In `printf("temp_llnode_ptr: %p\n", (void*)(*temp_llnode_ptr));`, `printf` is printing a line with the label `temp_llnode_ptr`, but it is passed `*temp_llnode_ptr`. So it does not print the value of the labeled thing, `temp_llnode_ptr`, but rather than value of what it points to. And in `free_LL_node(&(*list)->head);`, you pass the address of the `head` member to `free_LL_node`, which then frees the node it points to. Then it sets that pointer, the `head` member, to `NULL`. So you have lost the head of the list.

Comment: Why are you setting the value of the next pointer in the node you are freeing to null? Shouldn't you be setting the next pointer of the previous node to the node after the one you're freeing?

Comment: @Darrin `temp_llnode_ptr` doesn't point to the second node. It points to the `next` variable in the first node, which you just freed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `X` be the thing that `(*list)->head` points to. Then `temp_llnode_ptr` is set to the address of `X->next`. Calling `free_LL_node(&(*list)->head);` frees `X`. Once `X` is freed, the contents of its memory are no longer reliable. Among other things, they may well have been changed by the memory management routines, using that memory for its own purposes. `X->next` is in that memory, so its contents may have changed. Printing `(*temp_llnode_ptr)` attempts to print the contents of `X->next`.

Since `temp_llnode_ptr` points to an object which has been freed, its value is indeterminate, per the C standard. (This is correct, as specified by the C standard, after `free(p)`, the **value** of `p` is no longer determined. Even though `free` cannot change the memory used to hold `p`, its “value” in a semantic sense may be tied to other data in memory, and that data may be altered by `p`, so that its “value” is no longer determined.) Additionally, `*temp_llnode_ptr` attempts to use that memory, and the behavior of that is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: This comment actually helped me understand what I was doing wrong. I ended up implementing the functionality in a different way. But this helped me understand what I was messing up on so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the problematic part:

```
    temp_llnode_ptr = &(*list)->head->next;
    printf("temp_llnode_ptr: %p\n", (void*)(*temp_llnode_ptr));
    free_LL_node(&(*list)->head);
    printf("NEW temp_llnode_ptr: %p\n", (void*)(*temp_llnode_ptr));
```

The first line sets `temp_llnode_ptr` to point to the `next` variable in the first node.

The second line looks at the value in that variable (the value which is the address of the second node) and prints it.

The third line frees the first node.

The second line looks at the value in that variable - the variable which is part of the first node - which we just freed - and prints it. Because we just freed this variable we're not supposed to use it any more. In this case it looks like the memory management system has used that spot in memory to hold some pointer related to memory management. That doesn't matter though - that's not your problem - your problem is that you're not supposed to use it *at all* after you free it.

You seem to think that `temp_llnode_ptr` points to the next node. I think that works for your purpose, so you can do that. `temp_llnode_ptr` can be just a pointer (instead of a pointer-to-a-pointer a.k.a. double pointer) and then you have a bunch of extra `&`s and `*`s to delete as well.
If you do `temp_llnode_ptr = (*list)->head->next;` (delete an `&`) then temp_llnode_ptr will point to the next node (instead of pointing to `next` which points to the next node) and you should be able to work out the rest yourself.

Comment: I feel like this answer is explaining the same concept as the first one that was posted.  But that one helped me figure out my problem first so I accepted that one as the answer.  Thank you to both of you though.  You both helped me understand what it was that I was doing wrong.